# Saving login information on the heroku server in the whatsapp.web.js directory

Tags: node.js, heroku

I recently uploaded my project 'whatsapp.web.js' to heroku.
And I'm having a problem
1 Because the server is being reset for some time.
2 Because it is not possible to save files on the server then can not connect again
I use the multi-device feature in whatsapp
The question is is it possible to save the login information? And every time the server is reset it will reconnect